# Query is slow - large result

Tags: cassandra

This table:

```
CREATE TABLE buckets (
    year_month text,
    source_id uuid,
    nano_since_epoch bigint,
    max double,
    min double,
    num_values int,
    sum double,
    value double,
    PRIMARY KEY ((year_month, source_id), nano_since_epoch)
)
```

and this query:

```
select value from buckets where year_month = '2020_9' AND source_id=699ddcc0-5896-4b35-a901-8eec2f221499
```

It works, but the  query takes ~4 sec. to complete. Result set has ~48.000 rows.
Cluster has 3 nodes running on GCP, n1-standard-2 (2 vCPUs, 7.5 GB memory).
Not using SSDs. Almost same performance on the second DC with only 1 node, on a much larger -bare metal- machine.

Table histograms:

```
Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                              (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)                  
50%             0.00             51.01             73.46            182785             17084
75%             0.00             61.21            182.79           1629722            126934
95%             3.00            182.79            654.95           4055269            315852
98%             3.00            263.21            785.94           4866323            454826
99%             4.00            315.85            943.13           5839588            454826
Min             0.00              4.77             20.50                43                 0
Max             4.00           2816.16            943.13           5839588            454826
```

Is it possible to speed up fetching of the results or is the size of the result the limiting factor here?

**EDIT:**
Cassandra is running in docker on the VMS. Memory utilization on the VM is ~ 50%

Dockerfile:

```
services:
    elassandra:
        image: strapdata/elassandra:6.2.3.23
        container_name: elassandra
        environment:
            - CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS=10.164.0.58
            - CASSANDRA_SEEDS=10.164.0.58
            - CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=Prod Cluster 2
            - CASSANDRA_NUM_TOKENS=256
            - CASSANDRA_DC=datacenter-prod
            - CASSANDRA_RACK=rack1
            - LOCAL_JMX=no
        volumes:
            - '/opt/elassandra/data:/opt/elassandra/data'
            - '/var/log/cassandra:/var/log/cassandra'
            - '/var/lib/cassandra:/var/lib/cassandra'
        ports:
            - 7000:7000
            - 7001:7001
            - 7199:7199
            - 8080:8080
            - 8081:8081
            - 9042:9042
            - 9160:9160
            - 9200:9200
            - 9300:9300
        ulimits:
            memlock: -1
            nproc: 32768
            nofile: 100000
        network_mode: "host"
        logging:
            driver: syslog
            options:
              tag: cassandra-0
```

Comment: can you provide more information about node & Cassandra configuration. I think that the node size is the limiting factor here.  If you just run Cassandra, it gets less than 2Gb memory

Comment: I have edited the question with config details. As far as I can see the cassandra.yml is unchanged. VM shows a constant memory usage of ~50%

Comment: I can't say anything about elassandra - but I think that Cassandra instance doesn't have enough resources, and 48k results means that client needs to go to cluster 10 times, as results are paged by 5k items by default

Comment: You can treat elassandra just like cassandra in this case. What would you advice to adjust in order to improve the performance here?

Comment: give nodes more memory, better disks, more CPUs, tune JVM, ... But the main question here - do you really need Cassandra? I suspect that amount of data isn't so big, and postgres may handle it

Comment: The amount of data is increasing and will be big. The table in this example is currently rather small